# Opening local files on localhost

Tags: php, html, file

Im trying to open a pdf file from my local host through a php file, the link does nothing, though it works when I don't put the php file (after changing it to html) in C or D but when on the local host, it doesn't work probably because of http

I tried all the solutions but couldn't find away, I don't care which browser as long as it works.

I have IE 10, Firefox 23, and Chrome 3.0

Comment: Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code you have? Tip: make sure to use the relative path.

Comment: <a href="file://D:\table.png" target="blank">Click here</a>

Comment: ofcourse I tried file:/// and file://// and file:///// and file:///////

Comment: As I told you: **use the [relative path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing))**. For example: `table.png` or `../table.png`. There must be no `C:` nor `file:` in your path.

Comment: can you try relative path without file:

Comment: ofcourse relative works but I want to use C: or D: that's the point of my question @PetrR.

Comment: Well than the answer to your question is: **no**, you can't read any file from the client's computer.

Comment: @PetrR. I can already rename, copy, move, and delete files that are outside the root, there has to be a way to simply open them

Comment: You can *rename, copy, move, and delete files* with **pure HTML?** I really don't think so. You can do that with PHP, of course, but the only line of code you posted here doesn't look like you wanted to do that, so whatever your approach is, it's flawed. And **why do you want to use the absolute path anyway?** You will have issues once you want to copy your website outside your computer.

Comment: @PetrR. First of all I have no problem using php at all, and secondly I don't plan on putting it on a webserver, its just something I wanna use on my localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*That's how it is supposed to work.*

The `localhost` is where the **PHP** environment is configured to run. That's why it works there, not directly by clicking the HTML file from your C: or D: Drive.

Comment: Isnt there a way to enable the browser to open those files independently?

Comment: Are you are going to serve this HTML file from a webserver ?

Comment: No just from my localhost (XAMP)

Answer (score 3):

When you run files trough localhost they are run like if they are on server, so every path is calculated from file location, and you can link only 'visible' items (those in folder where your page is and deeper).

So if your page is in:

```
c:\mypages\htdocs\
```

then you have to put your pdf there and link it relativly:

```
c:\mypages\htdocs\index.html
c:\mypages\htdocs\pdf\somepdf.pdf

<a href="/pdf/somepdf.pdf">
```

---

Added:
You can open file in PHP, read it contents and output results.

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf'); //first send headers informing its pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="somename.pdf"'); //additional headers (proposed name will be 'somename.pdf')
readfile('example.pdf'); //link to orginal file (it does not have to be in 'visible' place)
die(); //not important but worth to add
```

Comment: yes ofcourse but the point of my question is to see if there is a workaround to do it with files outside the page root folder

Comment: I can already rename, copy, move, and delete files that are outside the root, there has to be a way to simply open them

Comment: hey i added some PHP which may help you